# How do you load more than 32 sounds on a single page using Corona SDK

Tags: android, iphone, audio, coronasdk

Is there any way to load more than 32 sounds on a single page using Corona SDK? I am developing a cross-platform app, the page uses a vertical scroll, and I have been unable to load more than 32 sounds. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may begin to run into memory constraints or OutOfMemoryExceptions if you attempt to load a substantial amount of audio into memory. Are you sure you want to do this? Can this data be lazy loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a limit imposed by the audio library on the number of sounds you can load at once.  Memory would be the constraint.  The "32"  limit is the number of simultaneous sounds you can play at once.  There are only 32 sound channels that can be mixed together at once.   But you could mix 32 sounds out of 100 loaded sounds.